# React Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code was originally supposed to just display a different greeting using the time of the day (*Date().getHours()*) and some conditions. However, I tried to simplify the code to just check if the state would change, it gives the same error mentioned above.

The state does get displayed as is if I don't include the conditions setting the state.

```
import React from 'react'
import Cards from './cards'

function Main() {

    const [greeting, setGreeting] = React.useState("Hello")
    const user = false
    if (user) {
        setGreeting("Welcome")
    } else {
        setGreeting("You dont belong here")
    }
    return (
        <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap pt-2 mt-2 mb-4">
                <h1> {greeting} Random Dude!</h1>
            </div>
            <Cards />
        </main>
    )
}


export default Main
```

I tried to wrap this in a function as well but no luck which makes sense because every time the code gets rendered, the function is called again and it loops

```
import React from 'react'
import Cards from './cards'

function Main() {

    const [greeting, setGreeting] = React.useState("Hello")
    const user = false
    function greetingMessage() {
        if (user) {
            setGreeting("Welcome")
        } else {
            setGreeting("You dont belong here")
        }
        return (greeting)
    }
    return (
        <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap pt-2 mt-2 mb-4">
                <h1> {greetingMessage()} Random Dude!</h1>
            </div>
            <Cards />
        </main>
    )
}


export default Main
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform setting your React state inside either an event handler or inside a useEffect hook.

What's happening in your code is this:-

1) `const user = false` :- This assignment happens every time the component re-renders so I think user should be React state and not a simple variable.

2) `<h1> {greetingMessage()} Random Dude!</h1>` - This means that whenever your component renders, `greetingMessage()` is called and the state is set as per your logic. Now since, the state is set, the component will re-render, which will trigger everything again and the cycle will go on. To solve this do this in a `useEffect` like so:-

```
//Just after your state definitions
useEffect(()=>{
        if (user) {
            setGreeting("Welcome")
        } else {
            setGreeting("You dont belong here")
        }
},[])
```

So your final code can be something like:-

```
function Main() {

    const [greeting, setGreeting] = React.useState("Hello")
    //Implement the logic for how you want to set this user state
    const [user,setUser] = React.useState(false)


    useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
            setGreeting("Welcome")
        } else {
            setGreeting("You dont belong here")
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap pt-2 mt-2 mb-4">
                <h1> {greeting} Random Dude!</h1>
            </div>
            <Cards />
        </main>
    )
}
```

My best bet for you is to once go through React docs about hooks before you jump directly into code. These will clear out a lot of things for you:-

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
import React from 'react'
import Cards from './cards'

function Main() {
    const user = false
    const [greeting, setGreeting] = React.useState(user ? "Welcome" : "You dont belong here")

    return (
        <main role="main" className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap pt-2 mt-2 mb-4">
                <h1> {greeting} Random Dude!</h1>
            </div>
            <Cards />
        </main>
    )
}


export default Main
```